# Test for any derived exception

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

Hello guys (and gals),

I'm using xUnit to build my test units in .NET and I'm trying to assert if a certain method throws an exception. I'm not really interested in the exact type of the exception, as long as it inherits from some base exception class. **How do I do it?**

I've searched all over Google for some way to do this out-of-box, but it seems I'd have to write my own class to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature already lives in xunit.net (v2-beta), but it is try-catch block to simply resolve your problem on current stable version(v1).

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    try
    {
        // some test logic....

        Assert.True(false, "Exception should be thrown.");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Here is another way.

```
[Fact]
public void AnotherTest()
{
    var exception = Record.Exception(() =>
    {
        /*test logic..*/
    });
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<Exception>(exception);
}
```